# Tags that can be added to drive organic SEO

Tags: seo, html, meta-tags, structured-data

Just working on a page template just wondered if there is any more useful tags/codes that can be added to drive organic SEO. We are planning to use Google/Bing Adwords, Google Merchant as well for some pages.

Here is a list of what I am using:

1. ```html
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   ```
2. ```html
   <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en-GB">
   ```
3. ```html
   <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ```
4. ```html
   <title>YOUR PRODUCT TITLE (60 characters)</title>
   ```
5. ```html
   <meta name="description" content="PRODUCT INFORMATION (160 characters)">
   ```
6. ```html
   <meta name="keywords" content="NO MORE THAN 10 KEYWORD PHRASES">
   ```
7. ```html
   !-- Social Media sharing meta code --> 
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="COMPANY/BRAND NAME" />
   <meta property="og:title" content=" TITLE OF PRODUCT/BRAND " /> 
   <meta property="og:description" content=" DESCRIPTION OF PRODUCT/BRAND" /> 
   <meta property="og:type" content="PRODUCT.GROUP" /> 
   <meta property="og:url" content="WEB ADDRESS" /> 
   <meta property="og:image" content="WEB ADDRESS IMAGE" /> 
   <meta name="twitter:card" content="SUMMARY" /> 
   <meta name="twitter:site" content="@COMPANY/BRAND NAME" /> 
   <meta name="twitter:title" content=" TITLE OF PRODUCT/BRAND " /> 
   <meta name="twitter:description" DESCRIPTION OF PRODUCT/BRAND " /> 
   <meta name="twitter:image" content=" WEB ADDRESS IMAGE " />
   ```
8. GOOGLE ANALYTICS CDOE
9. ```html
   <!-- JSON-LD markup generated by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. --> 
   <script type="application/ld+json"> 
   { 
   "@context" : "http://schema.org", 
   "@type" : "Product", 
   "name" : " TITLE OF PRODUCT", 
   "image" : " WEB ADDRESS IMAGE ", 
   "description" : " DESCRIPTION OF PRODUCT ", 
   "mpn" : " PRODUCT NUMBER", 
   "brand" : { 
   "@type" : "Brand", 
   "name" : " BRAND NAME ", 
   "logo" : "BRAND LOGO", 
   "URL" : "URL WEB ADDRESS PAGE" 
   } 
   } 
   </script>
   ```
10. Image `alt` tags on ALL IMAGES
11. Add in BACK LINKS

At present it is a information product page (so not showing any prices). Nor can they buy online, they will have to enquiry via phone/email. Any information/help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for help with the CTR of your organic listings / referral traffic i.e. by taking up more real estate / adding more enticing text on the SERPS with the added markup, or are you trying to increase your organic ranking positions? Schema / rich snippets / structured data etc. will help the former but no number of tags / metadata will affect your "SEO".

Comment: Don't forget `corporate contact` https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contact

Comment: I've closed this because you have asked for an entire list of items.  Please limit your question to something more specific.

Comment: Most of your tags have nothing to do with SEO anyway.    The title tag is the only tag of those that is really important for SEO.   Some of them like meta keywords, and Google Analytics snippet have absolutely nothing to do with rankings.

Comment: Double Clicked - Just really trying increase organic ranking positions but thanks for your input on the Schema / rich snippets / structured data stuff and corporate contact. I understand that metadata doesn't really do anything but i assume its sort of still useful to have?

Comment: Stephen Ostermiller - was only asking to see what else there could be that i might of missed?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use data types and properties to give Google enough info about your business to display rich snippets and knowledge graph. Those are specially:

- [breadcrumb](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb) (rich snippet)
- organization or [localBusiness](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business)
- [corporate contact](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contact) (knowledge graph)
- [social profile](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile) (knowledge graph)

Using of data type `Product` you aren't forced to publish a price - it isn't required property. Only on using of `Offer` is the `price` ruequired.